# Index not working properly while joining tables with two different engines (TokuDB and InnoDB)

Tags: mysql, innodb, tokudb

I am trying to join two tables which are on two different engines. One is on Innodb and other is on Tokudb.

Query is something like:

```
select * from table1 t1, table2 t2 where t1.a = t2.x and t1.b = 'xyz';
```

Here **table1** has a(indexed), b(indexed), c columns and has engine **innodb**
while **table2** has x(indexed), y, z columns and has engine **tokudb**

It is scanning through all the rows of table2 and using join type: ALL

Result of explaining the query

```
id  select_type table partitions type   possible_keys   key   key_len ref     rows  filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE      t1    NULL       const  b,a             b     303     const   1     100.00      NULL
1   SIMPLE      t2    NULL       ALL    NULL            NULL  NULL    NULL    20687 100.00      Using where
```

As you can see it is scanning over the entire table2. Am i missing something here? or is it because it is joining over two different engines?

Create Table Syntax

**table1**

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  `a` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `b` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `a` (`a`),
  UNIQUE KEY `b` (`b`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**table2**

```
CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `x` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `y` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `z` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `x` (`x`)
) ENGINE=TokuDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables.  I am fishing for datatypes and index definitions for at least `a` and `x`.

Comment: Did you install TokuDB with MySQL?  What versions of each?

Comment: Provided the "create table" for both tables. Also yes I have installed tokudb on Mysql. Both Innodb and tokudb versions are 5.7.25-28

Answer (score 1):

Use the same `CHARACTER SET` when joining:

```
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
) ENGINE=TokuDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
                                ^^^^^^
```